# JavaFx model equals always return false

Tags: java, model, javafx

I create an application, and I create model for `ObservableList` I want call the collection `.contains()` method which is requre `equals()` but this always return with false. I only put one field in the equals method. When I compare in if statement use getter method it returns true as I expect.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Client implements ObservableValue {

    private final SimpleStringProperty remoteAddress;
    private final SimpleStringProperty userName;
    private final boolean connected = true;
    private final ObservableList<String> logs
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<Image> imageLogs
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Client(String remoteAddress, String userName) {
        this.remoteAddress = new SimpleStringProperty(remoteAddress);
        this.userName = new SimpleStringProperty(userName);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty remoteAddressProperty() {
        return remoteAddress;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty userNameProperty() {
        return userName;
    }

    public final String getRemoteAddress() {
        return remoteAddress.get();
    }

    public final void setRemoteAddress(String name) {
        this.remoteAddress.set(name);
    }

    public final String getUserName() {
        return userName.get();
    }

    public final void setUserName(String name) {
        this.userName.set(name);
    }

    public ObservableList<String> getLogs() {
        return logs;
    }

    public ObservableList<Image> getImageLogs() {
        return imageLogs;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.remoteAddress == ((Client) obj).remoteAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.remoteAddress);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the actual string content of the properties:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.remoteAddress.get().equals(((Client) obj).remoteAddress.get());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.remoteAddress.get());
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: But why I can remove data from the `TableView`? I have recently removed data from the tableview (which contain Person class objects) by calling `table.getItems().remove(row.getItem())` even I didn't override equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: @UnKnown I don't really see how this is related to this question. Probably you need to post your own question, providing proper context for your code.

Comment: I posted new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427758/how-tableview-and-listviews-remove-works

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can't compare two objects with "==", use equals:

```
return this.remoteAddress.equals(((Client) obj).remoteAddress);
```

Comment: Again, that assumes `SimpleStringProperty` overrides `equals(...)`. It doesn't.

Comment: @James_D I deleted my answer (same as this one), as `equals` does return `false` even if the strings are `equal`. However according to the docs `equals` *is* overridden. According to the docs `SimpleStringProperty` inherits `equals` from `ReadOnlyStringProperty`, not from `Object`.

Comment: The only place I see [`equals(...)` in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html) is where it is inherited from `Object`. Similarly, in [`ReadOnlyStringProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyStringProperty.html) I do not see an `equals(...)` method.

Comment: @James_D It seems to have changed. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html   Since we don't know which version of Java OP is using, this answer might not necessarily be wrong.

Comment: Interesting. Unless it just delegated back to the default implementation, that wouldn't be a back-compatible change.