# How TableView and ListView's remove works?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, tableview

As I saw we have to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods to remove Custom class's object from the java Collection's `java.util.List` or similar others.

But I want to know how the `TableView` and `ListView`'s `remove` works? recently I successfully removed an custom class `(Person)`'s object from the `TableView`'s `ObservableList` ( after viewing the `ObservableList`'s `remove` method I realized it is inheriting the `remove(Object)` method from the `java.util.List` )

Then how it could be possible to remove the TableView's row by calling. `table.getItems().remove(row.getItem())` row contain Person class's object data and Person class didn't override `equals(object);` and `hashCode();` methods

Here is the complete code about this confusion.

```
public class RowMenu implements Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>> {

    @Override
    public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> table){
        final TableRow row = new TableRow();
        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        final MenuItem removeMenuItem = new MenuItem("Remove");
        removeMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(row.getItem());
                System.out.println(table.getItems().remove(row.getItem()));

            }
        });
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(removeMenuItem);
        row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                        .then((ContextMenu)null)
                        .otherwise(contextMenu)
        );
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like this has nothing to do with JavaFX, and you’re really asking how it’s possible to successfully remove an object from a Collection when that object’s class does not define custom equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: @VGR it has something todo with javafx contentwise

Comment: @VGR Specifically, it only works because the table view mechanism guarantees that `tableView.getItems().get(i) == row.getItem()` for some `i` (actually, `i` is `row.getIndex()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default comparison just uses object identity; i.e. if you don't override `equals(...)` then `object.equals(anotherObject)` is equivalent to `object == anotherObject`.

In that case, `list.remove(object)` will remove a `row` from `list` if the reference `object` is identically equal to a reference held by the list.

In this case:

```
table.getItems().remove(row.getItem())
```

will clearly work. `row.getItem()` returns the item displayed by the table row, which is the very same object that is held in the table view's backing list of data. (The table view mechanism passes a reference from the table view's backing list to the table row's `updateItem(...)` method.)

You only need to worry about overriding equals if you want to supply an argument to `remove(...)` that is `equal` to the object you want to remove, but might not be a reference to the actual same object in memory.